# How do I autowire OrmLite DAO instances into Spring Controllers?

Tags: spring, controller, dao, ormlite

So I'm using SpringBootApplication to create a quick server application.
I want to have persistence in this application as well, so I added OrmLite to handle my SQLite database.

Instantiating OrmLite DAOs requires a `ConnectionSource` to the database. How do I `@Autowire` this instantiated DAO with the `connectionSource`to my controller handling requests, so that I can return whatever they requested from the database? I also have a databaseHelper class that creates the connection to the database, it get instantiated in the application main method.

For example the controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

 @AutoWired
 GreetingDao greetingDao;
 //how does this instance have the connectionSource Dao to the database?

}
```

DAO:

```
@Component
public class GreetingDao {
 Dao<int, Greeting> greetingDao;

 public GreetingDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
  greetingDao = Dao.createDao(connectionSource, Greeting.class);
 }

}
```

Comment: Define a bean of type `ConnectionSource` in your application context.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after reading a bit further on this, I realized that I can just set default constructors for my DAO classes, and then when my application main is called, I just set the connectionSource for my DAO's in the ApplicationContext.

Then when I have `@Autowire` for my DAOs inside the controller classes, they will have the same instance that I set my connectionSource to.

```
//inside @SpringBootApplication class
public void main(String [] args) {
 ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)

 DatabaseHelper dbHelper = context.getBean(DatabaseHelper.class)
 dbHelper.connect();

 GreetingAccessor greetingAccessor = context.getBean(GreetingAccessor.class)
 greetingAccessor.createDao(dbHelper.getConnectionSource);
}

//inside GreetingAccessor
public void createDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
 greetingDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Greeting.class);
}
```